# OnTabSelected not being called at all when using actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I've done stuff like this before and this is a super simple example but I can't seem to get it working using actionbarsherlock v4.1.

This is the main activity

```
public class VanityActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {



/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        //restore
    }

    com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab();
    tab1.setText("Website");
    tab1.setTabListener(new HeaderTabListener(getApplicationContext()));
    tab1.setTag(1);
    actionBar.addTab(tab1);

    com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab tab2 = actionBar.newTab();
    tab2.setText("Portfolio");
    tab2.setTabListener(new HeaderTabListener(getApplicationContext()));
    tab2.setTag(2);
    actionBar.addTab(tab2);

    com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab tab3 = actionBar.newTab();
    tab3.setText("Team");
    tab3.setTabListener(new HeaderTabListener(getApplicationContext()));
    tab3.setTag(3);
    actionBar.addTab(tab3);

}


}
```

And my HeaderTabListener class:

```
public class HeaderTabListener implements   

com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.TabListener {

private Context context;

public HeaderTabListener(Context context){
    this.context = context; 
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    int i=((Integer)tab.getTag()).intValue();
    if(tab.getPosition()==0){
        ft.replace(android.R.id.content, CompanyFragment.newInstance(i));
    }else if(tab.getPosition()==1){

        ft.replace(android.R.id.content, PortfolioFragment.newInstance(i));
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    Log.v("Tab selected", tab.getText().toString());

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    Log.v("Tab selected2", tab.getText().toString());
}

}
```

And finally one of the fragments (both fragments are the same but the text in each layout is different)

```
public class PortfolioFragment extends SherlockFragment {
  private static final String KEY_POSITION="position";
  private static final String KEY_TEXT="text";

  static PortfolioFragment newInstance(int position) {
    PortfolioFragment frag=new PortfolioFragment();
    Bundle args=new Bundle();

    args.putInt(KEY_POSITION, position);

    frag.setArguments(args);

    return(frag);
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                           ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View result=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_portfolio, container, false);

    int position=getArguments().getInt(KEY_POSITION, -1);
    return(result);
  }
}
```

So when it first loads the the tabs are all displayed correctly, the first one his highlighted and the text in CompanyFragment layout displays. But then I am unable to click any of the other tabs to change the content and my logs inside of onTabSelected just never gets called. Any thoughts? Thanks for reading.

Comment: i am having the same problem . did u manage to solve it ?

Comment: I did but looking at working code and what I have above I can't find what I changed. I remember it being something really small...if you want to post your code I can try to help out.

Comment: Please have a look at the answer provided and accept it if it solved your problem!

Answer (score 0):

First off, let me tell you that I have no experience with ActionBarSherlock. I looked at your code to get a few ideas for my application. Seeing as it hasn't been answered since you posted it a few month ago, I would like to share my first impression.

As far as I know, ActionBarSherlock exposes the same functionality as the most recent Android APIs. Therefore, I do think that you are missing a simple method call. You would need to call `commit()` ([Android Developer Guide reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commit%28%29)) after you replace the fragment. Therefore, change the line, and all similar lines from;

`ft.replace(android.R.id.content, PortfolioFragment.newInstance(i));`
to
`ft.replace(android.R.id.content, PortfolioFragment.newInstance(i)).commit();`.

I hope this will solve your problem although I do realise you state that the ònTabSelected()` method is never called. Without debugging the difference between the problems would, however, seem transparent.